# Combining multiple CSS animations into one

Tags: css

I'm pretty new to programming and CSS animations so please excuse me if I'm using the wrong terms :-)

I have two animations on one element. I have an image of a man on a scooter that slides into the homepage (once) when it's loaded and then on hover it bounces (infinite).

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
 <section>
        <!--Animation and Welcome Heading-->
        <div class="welcome-container">
            <img id="scooter-animation" src="./images/Man_On_Scooter.png" alt="Man on Electric Scooter">
            <h1>welcome to suoto.</h1>
        </div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
/* Animated Scooter Slide-In */

@keyframes slide {
    100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

/* Animated Scooter Bounce on Hover */

@keyframes bounce {

    0%,
    100%,
    20%,
    50%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px)
    }

    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px)
    }
}

#scooter-animation {
    position: relative;
    left: -200%;
    -webkit-animation: slide 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation: slide 2s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

#scooter-animation:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    animation-name: bounce;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    left: 0% !important;
}
```

Everything is running perfectly except as soon as the mouse hovers anywhere else on the webpage, the animation disappears from screen and slides in again when I only want this to happen once. Does anybody have any idea what it is I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers and have a nice day!

Comment: Would be better if you can share your html too

Comment: I just added it!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code structure a bit and added Javascript but It should work now. Basically I gave initial class name for your image and I cancelled this class name after first render. As a result cancelling initial css feature from image fixed the problem.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', animate);

function animate() {
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('scooter-animation').classList.remove('slide'); }, 3000);
}
```

```css
/* Animated Scooter Slide-In */

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        left: -200%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

/* Animated Scooter Bounce on Hover */

@keyframes bounce {

    0%,
    100%,
    20%,
    50%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px)
    }

    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px)
    }
}

#scooter-animation {
    width:200px;
}
.slide {
   position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: slide 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation: slide 2s 1;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
#scooter-animation:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    animation-name: bounce;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section>
        <!--Animation and Welcome Heading-->
        <div class="welcome-container">
            <img class='slide' id="scooter-animation" src="https://d2mvzyuse3lwjc.cloudfront.net/doc/en/UserGuide/images/Pie_Of_Pie_Chart/Pie_Of_Pie_Chart.png?v=83478" alt="Man on Electric Scooter">
            <h1>welcome to suoto.</h1>
        </div>
 </section>
<body>
```

Comment: So I tried to add your code snippet but it still doesn't work. The hover works perfectly but the slide animation completely disappears.

Comment: Are you inserting Js to your html? It works in snipped of Stack over flow and also in this url https://jsfiddle.net/sdz6jo48/

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but also in the URL I can't see the initial slide-in :-(